# Modelling I2C capacitance for cables under water

Tags: sensor, i2c, serial, water, underwater

My setup works fine with following combination of hardware:
Raspberry Pi4 connected to a TCA9548A I2C Multiplexer from Texas Instruments, whereas each channel is connected over 4wires (GND, VCC, SDA, SCL) with 140cm 30awg silicone wires to two more I2C sensors.

In the office, the setup works perfectly. When the cables are immersed in water, which they need to be for the application, I get errors. Wrong addresses are displayed for the I2C sensors and it happens very very rarely that the sensors are recognized under their correct address and can also be read out.

My question is basically: How can I model the wire capacitance with regard to the surrounding water and maybe other relevant water parameters such as the electrical conductivity?

Comment: If the wires are in the same insulating sleeve, and there is *no* water between them, there should not be any capacitance change. You are probably having some other issues

Comment: Look at the signals on a scope in both scenarios

Comment: It's probably down to grounding and the presence of water supplies an extra (interfering) ground electric field connection to all sorts of random other bits of equipment. Use a differential form of signalling is my advice.

Comment: You don't need to connect your circuitry to find what happened, but you will call **Ah!** : Just dip an oscilloscope probe in the water.

Comment: Have you verified that immersing the cable in water has anything to do with capacitance? Do you have oscilloscope capture to prove this? Is this the same issue than with your previous question why I2C does not work properly on your setup?

Comment: Put a thin sleeve around the cables so that water does not get between the wires.

Comment: @user1850479 thank you! that could do.

Comment: @Andyaka could you please provide a reference for your idea? thank you!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean @MarcoBobinger

Comment: if you're in a place where you need to worry about such things, I2C, which is unbalanced open collector, is not what you want to be using. Something like RS422/485, which is low impedance and balanced would be my suggestion.

Comment: @danmcb  I concur about using differential buses.  I would also add CAN bus to the list.  There are also extenders which convert I2C to differential and back.  [LTC4331](https://www.analog.com/en/products/LTC4331.html), for example; there are a few more.  Extenders may be convenient, but using a differential bus from the start is cleaner architecture.  Marco may be pushing I2C too far outside of its intended application.  I've [done that once too](http://prolifictec.com/blog/2014/11/memoirs-of-overgrown-i2c-bus.html), although without water.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polymers' water uptake can vary a lot (e.g. https://omnexus.specialchem.com/polymer-properties/properties/water-absorption-24-hours#A-C ).

This water ingress changes the relative permittivity as already mentioned.  This is even used to build sensors (e.g. https://www.mdpi.com/1424-8220/18/5/1516/htm ). The final value strongly depends on the exact conditions and material composition but to give an idea, one can take a look at research papers like DOI:10.1109/TDEI.2015.005291 i.e. figure 3 (For a sneak peek look here: https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/A-capacitance-study-of-anomalous-diffusion-of-water-Gao-Liang/89f65da7fe71ba55a923a3876e801587781f1799/figure/4 ). In the mentioned publication an increase of the relative permittivity from 3.5 to 6.0 is reported for some of the investigated materials.

So how to deal with that?

1. Select the cable (isolation) carefully - ideally something with a very low water uptake and enough thickness
2. Keep the cable short as possible
3. Lower the switching frequency

EDIT: thinking about it, a coax cable might do the trick if it is hermetic.

EDIT2: if none of the approaches works one can try to use differential I2C bus extender. The trick is that differential transmission is less susceptible to signal perturbances. Downside is the additional HW requried.

Comment: I am using 30AWG silicone wires with a silicone thickness of 0.24mm around the 0.08mm diameter copper wires. Thanks for the references!

Answer (score 2):

Water has a dielectric constant of about 80 (compared to about 1 for air and perhaps 4 for plastic insulation), so the cable capacitance will be greater. How much depends on the construction of the cable.

You can measure it by dunking the cable and using your multimeter capacitance range.

Comment: thank you! That is a good approach. Is there also a way to reduce the capacitance? use thicker silicone around the cables or shield it with sth.?

Comment: It would only matter if the wires are immersed in the water without any insulation. If these are bundled inside a sealed sleeve, or even if just bundled tightly, so there is gaps between them I would not expect any capacitance difference.

Comment: @EugeneSh. If you think about the electric field lines I think it could be double or triple depending on the jacket thickness.

Comment: Ok.. I guess it worth an experiment

Comment: @EugeneSh. I think you are correct if the wire is shielded.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Intuitively I would neglect the field which goes outwards, even if unshielded but my intuition might be wrong.

Comment: An issue with some cables is the capacitance changes with pressure. We use this technique to test bespoke Ethernet cables up to 10kpsi. However, for your situation, you may have an issue where noise is being coupled in to your cable via the water path. The noise could be from your power supply or some other equipment. You can try running a wire from your circuit ground to the water and see if that helps. If that's the problem, perhaps using shielded cable will help or coupling your circuit ground via capacitors to the water.

Comment: @qrk thanks! The probes are immersed into metal containers filled with water. There is no grounding yet, I'll give it a try.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I use 30AWG wires with silicone and no shielding. I twisted 4 cables for VCC, GND, SDA and SCL. Here is the product that I purchased: https://www.amazon.de/Elektrischer-anschlie%C3%9Fen-Litzendraht-Kupferdraht-Temperaturbest%C3%A4ndigkeit/dp/B07TV4RJHJ/ref=sr_1_1_sspa?keywords=30%2Bawg%2Bkabel&qid=1638861560&sr=8-1-spons&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUExSjRFRllJM1FSVVZPJmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUEwMjMzMTQwQzdUUkpRRldBRE03JmVuY3J5cHRlZEFkSWQ9QTA3MzMxNzQzNVJXT1NKUEY0RE1TJndpZGdldE5hbWU9c3BfYXRmJmFjdGlvbj1jbGlja1JlZGlyZWN0JmRvTm90TG9nQ2xpY2s9dHJ1ZQ&th=1

Comment: @EugeneSh. the wires are twisted and have tight contact.